# Project not appearing as a DLL when I rebuild

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

When I do a clean and build in VS, one of my projects isn't appearing as a DLL in the bin folder. All the others are. Can anyone tell me what setting I'm missing please, as I'm sure it's an easy fix but I can't for the life of me figure it out...

Thanks

Comment: Maybe it is in the bin/Release folder whereas you look in the bin/Debug one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the reference for the problem project in the main project, right-click on it and select properties, then ensure the Copy Local property is set to true.

Comment: Thanks a million. I had a potential circular reference so must have removed the reference at some point. Got the references right and that solved it. Cheers, that was driving me nuts!